# How to add new icon to existing AppIcons class generated from fluttericon.com

Tags: flutter, icons

In an existing application, there is AppIcons class which contains icons in this format:

```
class AppIcons {
  AppIcons._();

  static const _kFontFam = 'AppIcons';
  static const String? _kFontPkg = null;

  static const IconData envelope = IconData(0xe800, fontFamily: _kFontFam, fontPackage: _kFontPkg);
}
```

In assets folder, there is also `AppIcons.ttf` file for all the icons. How can I add new icon to existing icons list in this format from `fluttericons.com`.

Answer (score 0):

the way that worked for me is to re-generate the font file from scratch by adding the same svg files + the new svg file, and then generate the font file again, and replace it by the original one, but this way would only work if you still/already have the old icons as svg files!

Comment: i have like 50 icons. I don't want to add them again and again. Imagine adding it many times